# The best way to divide work between threads when processing a queue of documents

Tags: java, multithreading

We have an application which processes a queue of documents (basically all the documents found in an input directory).   The documents are read in one by one and are then processed.  The application is an obvious candidate for threading since the results from processing one document are completely independent from the results of processing any other document.   The question I have is how to divide the work.

One obvious way to split the work is to count the number of documents in the queue, divide by the number of available processors and split the work accordingly (example, the queue has 100 documents and I have 4 available processors, I create 4 threads and feed 25 documents from the queue to each thread).

However, a coworker suggests that I can just spawn a thread for each document in the queue and let the java JVM sort it out.   I don't understand how this could work.   I do get that the second method results in cleaner code, but is it just as efficient (or even more efficient) than the first method?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Elliott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We have an application which processes a queue of documents ... how to divide the work?

You should use the great `ExecutorService` classes.  Something like the following would work.  You would submit each of your files to the thread-pool and they will be processed by the 10 working threads.

```
 // create a pool with 10 threads
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 for (String file : files) {
     threadPool.submit(new MyFileProcessor(file));
 }
 // shutdown the pool once you've submitted your last job
 threadPool.shutdown();
 ...
 public class MyFileProcessor implements Runnable {
     private String file;
     public MyFileProcessor(String file) {
        this.file = file;
     }
     public run() {
        // process the file
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, there are three ways to do work-splitting among threads.

First, static partitioning. This is where you count and divide the documents statically (i.e., without taking into account how long will it take to process each document). This approach is very efficient (and often easy to code), however, it can result in poor performance if documents take different amounts of time to process. One thread can accidentally get stuck with all long documents which will imply that it will run the longest and your parallelism will be limited.

Second, dynamic partitioning (you did not mention this). Spawn a fixed number of threads and let each thread work in a simple loop:

```
While not done:
  Dequeue a document
  Process document
```

In this manner you avoid the load imbalance. You incur the overhead of accessing the queue after the processing of each document but that will be negligible as long as each document's processing is substantially longer than a queue access (hence, I think you should be).

Third, let the JVM do your work-scheduling. This is where you span N threads and let them fight it out. This approach is rather simple but its downside is that you will rely heavily on JVMs thread scheduling and it can be very slow if JVM doesn't do a great job at it. Having too many threads that thrash each other can be very slow. I hope JVM is better than that so this may be worth a try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Don't spawn a thread for each document but schedule a Runnable task at a Threadpool that has e.g. as many threads as processors.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to split the documents that way. Just create a fixed number of worker threads (i.e. create two worker threads using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`), and each can only process one document at a time. When it has finished processing one document, it grabs a new document from a shared list.